# Getting Upload Image mime type is application/octet-stream

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, php-5.3

While uploading file I am getting mime-type as application/octet-stream.

I have come to know that 
Zend_Frameworks tries to determine the mimetype in two ways:

First it tries to use the PECL FILEINFO-Extension (which is not installed on every server)
    if the extension is not istalled it tries to use mime_content_type (a php function). This function however is deprecated as of php version 5.3

So what to do now? How can I be sure that user uploading a file is image only and not something else? How can I detect mime type of uploaded file?

Answer (score 1):

For images you can also rely on [`exif_imagetype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) but I would recommend that you install `finfo`.

See [this](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/master/phunction/Disk.php#L330) for an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Zend_File_Transfer validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html) to exlude types that you dont want :

```
    $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();

   // Does not allow MIME type application/pdf and application/zip .
   $upload->addValidator('ExcludeMimeType', false, array('application/pdf',
                                                  'application/zip'));
```

or you can also use IsImage validator which checks if a transferred file is a image file :

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();

// Checks whether the uploaded file is a image file
$upload->addValidator('IsImage', false);
```

Comment: oups , i meant ExcludeMimeType instead .

Comment: Took back my vote, the `ExcludeMimeType` approach is probably based on `finfo` and `mime_content_type` so it shouldn't work. The `IsImage` validator should.